# Should I store large tree in a database?

Tags: database, data-structures, tree, trie

I want to try writing a dictionary application. From other questions on SO, I learned about data structures that should be considered:

- [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAWG)
- [ternary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree)
- [double-array tree](http://linux.thai.net/~thep/datrie/datrie.html)

However, it may be just my prejudice, but storing data in binary file and mapping it in-memory directly to data structure seems much heavy-handed approach. I'd normally consider putting it in graph database, but I imagine that DB-related data overhead (ids, hashes and the like) can destroy space gains coming from using aforementioned structures, when compared to a trie.

The dictionary will be large, containing all words in English. Should I store it in some sort of database or refrain from it?

Comment: If you're going to use a database, you might as well leverage the database's data structures.

Comment: Databases have already implemented data structures to speed up searching: indexes.

Comment: All words in English is not large (approx 100K words) What should the graph / tree represent ?

Comment: @wildplasser: Your estimate is low by at least a factor of two. See http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/how-many-words-are-there-in-the-english-language, especially the last paragraph. Some estimates put the total number of English words at over 1 million.

Comment: Could be. It is still modest, in database terms.

Comment: @wildplasser: building a tree is needed for dynamic lookup based on a substring, i.e. a hint while typing. I plan to use Wiktionary data, which is 1.8 GB compressed. Wouldn't call it "modest" and since building a tree only adds data (words themselves are only the final nodes) it will only grow. At this level I'm inclined to think about space constraints.